# Can't find "Automatically link new work in this build" option in Azure-YAML-Build-Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

we recently converted our Azure Build Pipelines to YAML definition. Now I can't find the option *Automatically link new work in this build* anymore, which was available in the classic pipelines. It is not displayed in the pipeline settings menu, as I would have expected, see attached screenshot. Is it still available?

Edit: We are running Azure DevOps Server 2019.

[image: screenshot of pipeline settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "Automatically link new work in this run" has not yet been implemented in Azure DevOps Server 2019.

[image]

Comment: Is it available in Azure DevOps Server 2020?

Comment: Yes, it is available in server 2020.

Answer (score 0):

It should appear under settings:

[image: Pipeline Settings]

[image: Link work items]

Comment: Well, it does not... Also your menu looks slightly different then mine. Maybe a different ADO Server version. We are running 2019. (Edited that above.)

Comment: I'll retract my answer - your original post had not indicated you were on ADO Server.